# How to convert springboot project to spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, gradle

I am working on a project which is spring boot
I want to convert it into spring web mvc
I tried this using converting it to dynamic web module 3.0
I have added the WebAppInitializer  for dispatcher servlet 
and the view resolver
But when I deploy the war it gets deployed successfully but I get `HTTP 404` error

Is there anything else I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all Spring boot is a wraper for Spring MVC and other Spring modules.
if you are already working with Spring boot and you want to add the web module (Spring MVC) you just need to enter to your POM file and add:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

this will make a Spring MVC app, now how about the view resolver? well Spring will manage this in my case when I code with Spring MVC I implement Thymeleaf in order to do the views, so I also add:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

this views (html) are saved in the folder resources/templates

and thadaaaaaa the only thing I do in my controller is return the string to that template for example

```
@GetMapping("/detail/{id}")
private String publicationDetail(@PathVariable Integer id, Model model) {

    Optional<CatalogEntity> product = catalogService.getProducById(id);
    model.addAttribute("product",product.get());

     counter(model);



    return "/catalog/detail";
}
```

but if you don't use Thymeleaf it should also work returning the String of your view but just save it inside the folder I mentioned

[image]